# CORS issue with Camunda Form JS SDK

Tags: cors, tomcat8, camunda

There is [an example](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/sdk-js/browser-forms) of Camunda BPM JS SDK usage being deployed to the default http://localhost:8080 domain. I would like to run that example on my own domain. Say http://localhost:8000 running simple PHP or plain HTML page. Naturally I receive `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access` issue. I add [this snippet](https://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html) to `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml` and restart Tomcat. And it looks like this has no effect at all. I tried to add

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but still no any effect.

Could someone suggest any settings to modify to let JS SDK usage on other domains?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, this is `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/engine-rest/WEB-INF/web.xml` should be edited to apply CorsFilter settings.